# How to convert two different strings to date and store it in single column in MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, date

Currently I'm working on `PHP` and `MySQ`L Project. I'm taking `DATE INPUT` from users in string format. So user can enter any format in `text-box`. For e.g. **dd/mm/yyyy** or **dd-mm-yyyy** or **yyyy-mm-dd** or **mm/dd/yyyy** etc. (I know its too bad practice). But my question is:

> is it possible to convert these all in single format and store it in
>   single column?

.

For converting I'm using `str_to_date()` function, but it accepts only one format to convert. How can I add other formats to convert string to date ?

Comment: PHP has some pretty smart tools for guessing dates.

Comment: not possible, you can think about a scenario where user think to enter "12-JUN-2018" in 06-12-2018. and we can say it to "06-DEC-2018" and "12-JUN-2018" and both are true. So I think its not possible, better give a date picker to user and let them pick a date from object at UI itself.

Comment: You want to be able to accept both dd/mm/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy? How do you expect to possibly be able to tell whether a date such as '01/02/2018' is the 1st Feb or 2nd Jan?

Comment: @Vivek what if I restrict user to enter date in dd/mm/yyyy and dd-mm-yyyy, it is possible to convert these two formats in yyyy-mm-dd format ans store it in single column in database ?

Comment: @GaneshAher: Yes definitely you can convert to any format from a known format.

Answer (score 1):

try this, should work:

```
$mysqlFormatedDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($yourTime));
```

PHP will take $yourTime and resolve it's format, then it will convert it to unix timestamp, and then it will convert to mysql datetime format which is Y-m-d H:i:s then you just need to save it to your DB.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in your mysql_query using STR_TO_DATE:

```
STR_TO_DATE($yourTime, '%c/%e/%Y %r')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "RLIKE()" to check fo some patterns but that will fail because you can't differentiate between international and retarded. Imagine someone typing in "12/11/2018". Is it the 11th of December or 12th of November? Also you wrote "e.g.", so if you allow everything, what would you make of "20122007"? 20th December 2007, 20th July 2012?
Use a JS-Library for date inputs or do inputs for day, month and year separately. Otherwise it's pretty hopeless.